# Polar Coordinates Double Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

$I = \int_{0}^{2} \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} x^2y^2 dy dx $

I must evaluate this using polar coordinates.

I have worked out this must be a circle of equation $x^2+y^2 \leq 4$. So the new limits must become $0$ and $2\pi$, and then $0$ and $2$.

My only confusion is how to write $x^2y^2$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain
$$
D =
\Big\{
\ (x,y)\:\ 0\le x\le 2\ ,\ y^2\le 4-x^2\ 
\Big\}
$$
is the part of the unit disk in $\Bbb R^2$ centered in $(0,0)$ with radius one which lives in the quadrants I and IV.

We substitute $x = r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$ and obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \int_0^2 dx\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{+\sqrt{4-x^2}} x^2\;y^2\; dy
\\
&=\int_D x^2y^2\; dx\; dy\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}dt\int_0^2(r^2\cos^2 t)(r^2\sin^2 t)\; r\; dr\\
&=\left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}\frac 18\sin^2(2t)\;d(2t)\right)
\left(\int_0^2 r^5\; dr\right)
\\
&
=\frac 18\cdot\frac {2^6}6\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\sin^2 u\;du
=\frac 43\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac 12(1-\cos 2 u)\;du
=\frac 43\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac 12\;du
\\
&=\frac{4\pi}3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Computer check, here using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: var('x,y,r,t');
sage: integral( integral( x^2*y^2, y, -sqrt(4-x^2), +sqrt(4-x^2) ), x, 0, 2 )
4/3*pi
sage: integral( integral( (r*cos(t))^2*(r*sin(t))^2 *r, r, 0, 2 ), t, -pi/2, pi/2 )
4/3*pi
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember your standard conversions:
$$x=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$

Just substitute these in, and don’t forget about your extra factor of $r$ from the Jacobian.

Comment: That gives $r^5 \sin^2(\theta) \cos^2(\theta)$

Comment: @NikitaMazepin that is correct, yes :)

Comment: @NikitaMazepin are you having trouble with the integral? If you’re integrating theta first then you just have to apply reduction rule or product to sum for the trig to find the inner integral, and the r integral becomes trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't I use the double angle formula for $\sin$, then it shouldn't be too difficult?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin yep, that works too!